# Linq select records that match a list of IDs

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to change my query below, so that it uses the `types` list within a contains type query.

So instead of having:

```
var cust = db.Customers.Where(x => x.type_id==9 || x.type_id==15 || x.type_id==16).ToList();
```

...I would have something like:

```
List<int> types = new List<int> { 9, 15, 16 };
var cust = db.Customers.Where(x => types.contains(x.type_id).ToList();
```

(type_id is not the primary key).

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: you are right. Just use 'Contains' instead of 'contains'

Comment: http://www.codeducky.org/sql-queries-in-linq/#where is a blog post that translates common SQL queries into LINQ.  It has an example for `WHERE IN` and other common SQL queries.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, method `List<T>.Contains` will be translated into SQL IN operator:

```
var cust = db.Customers.Where(x => types.Contains(x.type_id)).ToList();
```

Generated query will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE type_id IN (@p0, @p1, @p2)
```